# How to get this kind of parameter in node.js express router?

Tags: node.js, parameters, express, router

I have a router like this:

```
app.get('/blog/:id/delete', function (req, res) {

})
```

how can I get the `:id` parameter?

I have tried `req.query.id`  `req.param.id` ,but both failed

How can I get the correct `id` value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's `req.params.id`.

So, basically you were nearly right, just an `s` was missing ;-)